# Python 3 Chrome Selenium Keep Downloaded Jar File

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium, Chrome, and Python 3.

Here's what I'm doing to set everything up

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

chrome_options = Options()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": r"C:\Download\Dir",
    "download.directory_upgrade": "true",
    "download.prompt_for_download": "false",
    "disable-popup-blocking": "true",
    'download.neverAsk.saveToDisk':   'application/octet-stream, application/json, jar, ' +
                                                'text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, application/csv, ' +
                                                'application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, ' +
                                                'application/vnd.msexcel, text/anytext, text/plaintext, ' +
                                                'image/png, image/pjpeg, image/jpeg, application/zip',
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
chrome_options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection')
```

Then I have some credential secrets imported, and some website navigation to get to the file to download.

Afterwards, I click on the link to download the file:

```
# Click Upgrade Jar File
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="accordionPanel:j_id_3a:1:j_id_3j"]').click()
```

The problem I have is here. Chrome asks me if I'd like to keep the jar file after I've downloaded it.

---

[image]

---

I've been reading through a lot of documentation and I don't understand how I can circumvent this. I  believe that it should be added to `prefs` or as an `chrome_options.add_argument` but so far I've had no luck with the options I've found.

---

### Update 01:

A little update, I was able to get it to work "silently", which allows you to bypass the "keep" button, but I haven't yet found a solution that will bypass the "keep" button when you're looking at the GUI.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": r"C:\Download\Dir",
    "download.directory_upgrade": "true",
    "download.prompt_for_download": "false",
    "disable-popup-blocking": "true",
    "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
    "default_content_settings": "contentSettings",
    "download": "download"
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection')
```

---

### Update 02

Adapted code from a comment:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import os

# Secrets
user_id = [grabs from a function that queries secrets]
user_password = [grabs from a function that queries secrets]
download_dir = "C:\Download\Dir"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])


prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": r"C:\Download\Dir",
    'download.prompt_for_download': False,
    'download.extensions_to_open': 'jar',
    'safebrowsing.enabled': True
}

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
capabilities.update(options.to_capabilities())

driver = webdriver.Chrome('.\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

url = 'URL GOES HERE'

driver.get(url)

print("Navigating to", url)
driver.get(url)

# Define Text Boxes For Login
print('Logging into GoAnywhere Website')
username = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('secret')

# Enter Username/Password
username.send_keys(user_id)
password.send_keys(user_password)
password.send_keys('\n')

# Wait for Page to load
```

....[Navigation Logic Here]....

```
# Click Upgrades
print("Selecting Upgrades")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="accordionPanel"]/div[5]').click()

# CLick Upgrade Jar File
time.sleep(1)
print("Downloading upgrade jar to", download_dir)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="accordionPanel:j_id_3a:1:j_id_3j"]').click()
```

....[Logic to do stuff with file after downloaded]....

---

Comment: What happens when you click this:  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="accordionPanel"]/div[5]').click()?  Does it open another page?

Comment: Same page, just navigating the GUI of the site. They're not like ahrefs to other pages.

Comment: This is hard to troubleshoot without having access to your site.  I would play around with the Navigation Logic to see if that could be causing an issue.  You might be able to collapse that logic into one xpath call for testing.  I also always put my clicking code separate.

Comment: Are you logging into a corporate GoAnywhere account?

Comment: Yeah, I'm automating the download of the upgrade jar file.

Comment: Who controls the upload and security control related to this file?  Is your development box controlled by a Windows domain controller or by a corporate IT administrator?

Comment: Do you have any answers for my last comment here and on my answer? I need these items to help troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Sorry, been busy, I don't know who has control over it. But I think it's a corporate IT admin.

Comment: No worries.  I retested my answer with additional sites that have *.jar files.*  I haven't gotten the message "This type of file can harm your computer."  I am confident that your issue is related to your system and the GoAnywhere corporate account.  The latter has multiple security features that can be enabled by a corporate IT admin. Also if you're using a corporate Windows computer it also can be configured to display this warning message in the system registry.  It is impossible for me to troubleshoot this issue without having accessing to your computer and the GoAnywhere  account.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you consult with your corporate IT administrators to see if they can help you troubleshoot your issue that likely involves corporate security controls that cannot be circumvented using *Python Selenium.*

Comment: Let me know what you find out from corporate IT, because I want to know why my code isn't working for your specific situation.

Comment: I no longer have that option unfortunately I'm no longer working in that environment. I was able to get it working properly with the `--headless` flag, which is really all it needed. I was mostly curious as to why it works headless, but not when it's a visible GUI.

Comment: I updated my answer after doing more research into why my code didn't work in your corporate environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE 05-28-2021

---

After doing some more testing I have determined the code below works flawlessly on a *Microsoft Windows platform* that does not have any type of Chrome Browser policies enabled.

The code *will likely fail* when the *Microsoft Windows platform* is under **corporate IT control**.  *Google* has policy templates that allow corporate IT to set *Chrome* politics that can override the *selenium* code within this answer.

For example this is one of the politics that can be set by corporate IT that will negate the *selenium* code within this answer.

If either *SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel_StandardProtection* or *SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel_EnhancedProtection* are enabled Google Chrome will ***Gives you warnings about potentially risky sites, downloads, and extensions.***

```
 CATEGORY !!SafeBrowsing_Category
        POLICY !!SafeBrowsingExtendedReportingEnabled_Policy
          #if version >= 4
            SUPPORTED !!SUPPORTED_WIN7
          #endif
          EXPLAIN !!SafeBrowsingExtendedReportingEnabled_Explain
          VALUENAME "SafeBrowsingExtendedReportingEnabled"
          VALUEON NUMERIC 1
          VALUEOFF NUMERIC 0
        END POLICY

        POLICY !!SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel_Policy
          #if version >= 4
            SUPPORTED !!SUPPORTED_WIN7
          #endif
          EXPLAIN !!SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel_Explain

          PART !!SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel_Part  DROPDOWNLIST
            VALUENAME "SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel"
            ITEMLIST
              NAME !!SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel_NoProtection_DropDown VALUE NUMERIC 0
              NAME !!SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel_StandardProtection_DropDown VALUE NUMERIC 1
              NAME !!SafeBrowsingProtectionLevel_EnhancedProtection_DropDown VALUE NUMERIC 2
            END ITEMLIST
          END PART
        END POLICY
```

I also noted this within Chrome's source code.  This is why the message *"This type of file can harm your computer"* is thrown when downloading a *.jar* file

```
namespace download_util

static const struct Executables {
    const char* extension;
    DownloadDangerLevel level;
} g_executables[] = {

// Some files are dangerous on all platforms.

truncated...

  // Java.
{ "class", DANGEROUS },
{ "jar", DANGEROUS },
{ "jnlp", DANGEROUS },

truncated...
```

*Jar files* are considered dangerous by *Google Chrome*.  The verbiage below is from *Chrome's GitHub repository.*

***Note the text below is taking about displaying warning messages in the User interface (UI) of the Chrome browser.***

> platform_settings.danger_level: (required) Controls how files should be handled by the UI in the absence of a better signal from the Safe Browsing ping. This applies to all file types where ping_setting is either SAMPLED_PING or NO_PING, and downloads where the Safe Browsing ping either fails, is disabled, or returns an UNKNOWN verdict. Exceptions are noted below.
>
> The warning controlled here is a generic "This file may harm your computer." If the Safe Browsing verdict is UNCOMMON, POTENTIALLY_UNWANTED, DANGEROUS_HOST, or DANGEROUS, Chrome will show that more severe warning regardless of this setting.
>
> This policy also affects also how subresources are handled for "Save As ..." downloads of complete web pages. If any subresource ends up with a file type that is considered DANGEROUS or ALLOW_ON_USER_GESTURE, then the filename will be changed to end in .download. This is done to prevent the file from being opened accidentally.
>
> This policy also affects also how subresources are handled for "Save As ..." downloads of complete web pages. If any subresource ends up with a file type that is considered DANGEROUS or ALLOW_ON_USER_GESTURE, then the filename will be changed to end in .download. This is done to prevent the file from being opened accidentally.
>
> - NOT_DANGEROUS: Safe to download and open, even if the download was accidental. No additional warnings are necessary.
> - DANGEROUS: Always warn the user that this file may harm their computer. We let them continue or discard the file. If Safe Browsing returns a SAFE verdict, we still warn the user.

### CONCLUSION

---

> The OP of this question stated in the comments that he was using a corporate IT controlled computer. It is HIGHLY LIKELY that SafeBrowsingProtection was enabled on the OP's system.  With this extra level of security protection enforced by corporate IT the selenium code within this answer could not suppress the warning message being displayed in the OP's Chrome browser UI.
>
> The OP stated that he was able to bypass the "This type of file can harm your computer" message when using selenium and Chrome in headless mode.  The reason the message was suppressed is because headless mode does not use a UI thus the warning message will not be raised. Chrome's own documentation/source validates that this warning message is only displayed in the UI.  Ref: *platform_settings.danger_level* above.

### ORIGINAL POST 05-12-2021

---

The code below allows me to click on a href link for a *.jar file* without receiving *"This type of file can harm your computer"* message.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])


prefs = {
    'download.default_directory': 'download_directory',
    'download.prompt_for_download': False,
    'download.extensions_to_open': 'jar',
    'safebrowsing.enabled': True
}

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

# I used this site in my testing, because it had JAR files
url_main = 'http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/demos/'

driver.get(url_main)


driver.implicitly_wait(20)

# download a jar file
download_jar_file = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-70"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/a')
download_jar_file.click()
```

the preference *download.extensions_to_open* is linked to this policy in the *Chrome's* source code.

```
"AutoOpenFileTypes" : {
    "os": ["win", "mac", "linux", "chromeos"],
    "policy_pref_mapping_tests": [
      {
        "policies": { "AutoOpenFileTypes": ["exe", ".txt", "pdf"] },
        "prefs": {
          "download.extensions_to_open_by_policy": {"value" : ["exe", "pdf"] }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

```
----------------------------------------
My system information
----------------------------------------
Platform:     macOS
Python:       3.8.0
Selenium:     3.141.0
Chromedriver: 90.0.4430.24
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just gave this a try, and I'm getting the same result. File downloads fine, but after it asks if I want to "keep" the file.

Comment: Did you test my code as is (which works) or did your integrated my code with yours?  If it is latter, I need to see how you integrated the code.

Comment: Yeah, the only thing I changed was the download dir, and I had to add clicks on the website, along with login credentials, but that was just to navigate to the page where the download is.

Comment: My code as is works as you requested with the site *jgoodies.com*.   Your updated code doesn't match what I posted.

Comment: The updated code was just do demo the `--headless`. But I can post another update with your solution.

Comment: If I integrated your *options* and your *prefs* into my code, then the message "This type of file can harm your computer" returns.  Without your code integrations my code works as requested.

Comment: I must be missing something, but I've updated the main question again, so you can let me know if you see any syntax I failed to bring over or if I accidently left something in.

Comment: I know that my code example works for the site that I used in my test.  I'm trying to figure out why your site would work.  What version of Selenium and Chromedriver are you using?

Comment: How would I go about checking the versions of Selenium and Chromedriver?

Comment: import selenium
print (selenium.__version__)

Comment: print(driver.capabilities['browserVersion']) 
print(driver.capabilities['chrome']['chromedriverVersion'].split(' ')[0])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232310/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-pyrometheous).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `chrome_options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection')` in your chrome options setup.

Edit:

Wait a second. You've defined `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`. Try setting the arguments like this?

```
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection')
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. Still getting the same message after the file downloads.

Comment: do you have, in Chrome, selected the option `"Protect you and your device from dangerous sites"`? If not I think you need to do that too.

Comment: The browser window that comes up has it set to standard protection. Is there a flag or option that will turn that to No protection?

Comment: It should have standard protection to work.  Well, I'm out of ideas. I hope you or someone else can figure this out.

Comment: I appreciate it, hopefully someone will be able to help.

Comment: Quick note on this one. I've noticed that the chrome_options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection') comes after the chrome initialization. Can you try again after you move the 3 chrome_options before this line "driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)" ?

Comment: @art_architect I think this is ordered correctly/has the right syntax. But your suggestion is certainly worth a try.

Comment: @Pyrometheous see my edit for another idea to try.

Comment: @C.Peck, yeah, I noticed that with the options shortly after. I have it working now, but it only works with `options.add_argument("--headless")`. @art_architect I tried re-arranging to after the `driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`, but that didn't make a difference. Technically, it works now, but I'd still like to know why it doesn't work with the browser gui visible.

Comment: @Pyrometheous can you please share the code you are currently running? I am curious about the headless thing too

Comment: Sure, I'll add it as an edit to the original post, so it's easier to read.